# Django Form Wizard: Skip a step but still provide data

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I am creating a form using django form wizard.

The first step is a user selection, but based upon permissions, some users can only select themselves. If this is the case, there is no reason for them to see the user selection step (as the user will just be the current user). I would like to skip this step, but still provide the data (the current user) to the form.

Later, I am accessing that step's data to prefill other fields, so I need to save the data somewhere. I could handle this with multiple if checks seeing if the form data exists, if not, get the current user...etc, but this seems messy. Is there a way to tell the form wizard to not totally skip the step, but just not show it?

--EDIT TO ADD CODE--

```
class EmployeeLocationForm(SessionWizardView):

    form_list = [
        ('employee', EmployeeForm),
        ('location', LocationForm),
    ]
    template_dict = {
        'employee': 'reassignment/form_wizard/employee_location/employee.html',
        'location': 'reassignment/form_wizard/employee_location/location.html',
    }

    # THIS IS THE STANDARD WAY TO SKIP A FORM
    condition_dict = {
        'employee': show_employee_selection
    }

    def get_form_kwargs(self, step=None):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(step)
        if step == 'location':

            # IF FORM IS SKIPPED, THERE IS NOT STEP CALLED 'EMPLOYEE' TO GET DATA FROM 
            employee = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('employee')
            kwargs['current_location'] = getattr(employee, 'location', None)
        return kwargs

    def get_form_initial(self, step):
        initial = super().get_form_initial(step)

        # IF FORM IS SKIPPED. THIS NEVER GETS SET
        if step == 'employee':
            return self.request.current_user.employee
        return initial

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            location_kwargs = {}

            #THIS FAILS BECAUSE THERE IS NO EMPLOYEE STEP
            [location_kwargs.update(self.get_cleaned_data_for_step(step)) for step in ['employee', 'location']
            location = Location.objects.create(**location_kwargs )
```

So ideally, I would still be able to set initial, validate the data, and do all the regular form wizard stuff on the 'employee' step, it would just not display under some conditions. It would still be in the form_list, and would be using initial data.

Comment: Could you add some code?  Hard to imagine the setup/environment without any code

Comment: @phanti I added the wizard view and some comments. Does that help?